# How do you get two `match`es at the same time to work?

Tags: indentation, highlight

I have two `match` lines in my vimrc. they work when they are used by themselves but when i try to uncomment both i don't get any `match`ing behavior:

```
" highlight spaces used for indenting
match Visual /^\t*\zs \+/
" highlight overlength characters
match Visual /\%81v.\+/
```

**How do you get both `match` "indenting spaces" and `match` "characters past 80 column" to match at the same time?**

Rewriting the original question to be more generic: **How do you get two `match`es at the same time to work?**

p.s. If you are wondering why I have these specific `match`es. The `match`es are used to help enforce the correct indentation style (the above `match`es are for tab-indentation and I have some `match`es for spaces-indentation).

Comment: I experimented with changing the order of the match commands... that's when i discovered that the `match` command only enables the most recent `match` but the documentation does not seem very clear on that caveat/behavior... at least to me.

Comment: The other misleading factor for me at least is that [the article I read talking about `match`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) does not mention anything about the fact that you can only have one `match` active at a time (and further `match`es require `2match` and so on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `2match` for your second match.

```
" highlight spaces used for indenting
match Visual /^\t*\zs \+/
" highlight overlength characters
2match Visual /\%81v.\+/
```

There's also `:3match`, but this is used by the pre-installed `matchparen` standard plugin (see `:help :3match`), so if you need more matches than this, you're probably best off using the `matchadd()` function, or using syntax highlighting instead.

Alternatively, if you're using the same highlighting group, as you are, you can combine your regular expressions with `\|`:

```
" highlight spaces used for indenting and overlength characters
match Visual /^\t*\zs \+\|\%20v.\+/
```

Comment: `3match` is supposed to be only used by the matchit plugin. You can also combine your various regula expressions into a single one, e.g. `\(re1\)\|\(re2\)`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I was just in the process of updating my answer regarding the `matchparen` plugin. I'll add your note about combining regular expressions, though.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I am aware that you can combine multiple patterns in one `match` using regex syntax. However doing so is less elegant because I very strongly prefer to have a comment line pre-ceding each match to describe the function/purpose of the `match` command. So if I ever needed more than 3 I would probably go the extra mile and figure out the syntax required to call `matchadd()` function.

Comment: if i have 3 or more `match`es, should I not use `3match` because it is reserved for use by `matchparen` (so it's off limits)? should I instead use the `matchadd()` function?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Well, that depends on whether you're actually using `matchparen` or not. But essentially, yes.

Comment: i don't know what is `matchparen` and so I am not actively using it. I guess what you are saying is "if you use `matchparen` then don't use `3match`"?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith It's a standard plugin, and it's loaded by default, (see `:h standard-plugin`), so if you don't know what it is, it's more likely you *are* using it. If you've actively disabled it, though, then you're safe to use `:3match`

Comment: I would always go with the `matchadd()` functions, they are easier to use and handle (cleaning up etc)